# Add hosts to a job on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

Currently there are many (> 5) Jenkins nodes (aka slaves).
On each of those nodes there is a file with hosts.

Those hosts have to be available on each of nodes (> 5 files) and, unfortunately, they interfere with global configuration of those machines.
A change of any of those hosts requires updating > 5 files on different machines.

I would like to add some sites to hosts at a job level.
Those hosts would be available for this job only in a sandboxed environment, so that it is easily configurable (only in one place: in job's configuration) and not available globally.
How can this be achieved?

Comment: I don't think this question is entirely off topic of testing since we can / often might use Jenkins, however you might get a better response on a Jenkins forum.

Comment: Seems to be a good hint, @ChrisKenst. Thanks.